# How to find whether a point in a 3D space lies inside a hemisphere?

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, vector-graphics

```
Tip of the hemisphere - (x,y2,z)
Mid point of the circle in the hemisphere - (x,y,z)
```

As x,y,z and y2 can be anywhere in the 3D space, the hemisphere could point any direction and so I am struggling with the direction part. I can't solve this similar to a cone, sphere or a truncated cone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us call your point (a,b,c). Note that a hemisphere is the intersection of a half-space and a sphere. So we just test intersection with both and AND the result. First test whether the point is on the right side of the half-space:

```
dy = y2-y;

if (b-y)*dy<0 then
  return no intersection
```

This uses the fact that the distance of the tip to the center will have a different sign than the distance of the point to the center only if the test point is in the wrong half-space.

Then check versus the sphere. This is inferred from the distance of the tip to the center:

```
squareDistance = (x-a)²+(y-b)²+(z-c)²;
if squareDistance > dy² then
  return no intersection
else
  return intersection
```

Comment: Your second condition checks whether the point lies in the sphere of radius dy. Shouldn't it be (x-a)²+(y-b)²+(z-c)²? I also don't understand the first condition.

Comment: Which part do you not understand? You could also write it as `if NOT same_sign(b-y, y2-y) then...` if that makes it any clearer.

Comment: You're right on the square-distance of course- fixed it!